# Relogin without password

Tags: login, kde

I know how to set up KDE so that I can initially login without a password.  But is there a way to enable login without a password following a logout?

Comment: Oh wait, you want to use password once, then disable it?

Comment: That's just a very Unique Scenario, If you Log Out and require a password to log in, there is not (and shouldn't be) any way around this.

Comment: Logging out and then logging back in again gives me a way of terminating my active processes without having to do a full restart.  It's useful when there's something seriously messed up but I don't know how to fix it.  I think of it as a soft restart.  At the same time I don't want to lose the option of logging in as a different user, though I only very occasionally do that.

Comment: Ideally, the login screen would show my password greyed out, and pressing Enter would log me in.

Comment: My initial login is fully automatic, which is how I want it to be.  I just want subsequent logins to be the same.